# how to use if else function in the value of bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView in yii?

Tags: if-statement, yii

I use if else function in the TBGridView in yii framewoek set,

```
array(
        'name'=>'tstatus',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'150px'),
        'value'=>'
            if($data->tstatus==B2bTicket::UNACTIVATED){
                $data->tstatus=="未激活";
            }elseif($data->tstatus==B2bTicket::YUYUE_PROCESSING){
                $data->tstatus=="预约处理中，可取消";
            }elseif($data->tstatus==B2bTicket::YUYUE_CONFIRM){
                $data->tstatus=="预约确认，电话取消";
            }elseif($data->tstatus==B2bTicket::FINISHED){
                $data->tstatus=="体检完成";
            }else{
                $data->tstatus=="取消预约";
            }',
        'filter'=>CHtml::dropDownList('B2bTicket[tstatus]',$model->tstatus,  
            array(
                ''=>'全部',
                B2bTicket::UNACTIVATED=>'未激活',
                B2bTicket::YUYUE_PROCESSING=>'预约处理中，可取消',
                B2bTicket::YUYUE_CONFIRM=>'预约确认，电话取消',
                B2bTicket::FINISHED=>'体检完成',
                B2bTicket::YUYUE_CANCEL=>'取消预约',
            )
        ),

    ),
```

but there are a error occured:rse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in

```
    D:\xampp\htdocs\marvel_b2b\sources\trunk\web\protected\framework
\base\CComponent.php(606) : eval()'d code on line 2
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: did you try like `($data->tstatus==B2bTicket::UNACTIVATED?...:..)`?

Answer (score 1):

if I understand you correctly, by your assigning `==` you should use single `=` ,

and you could use a unanimous function to do the job

```
'value' => function($data){

    $msg = '';
    if($data->tstatus==B2bTicket::UNACTIVATED){
        $msg ="未激活";
    }elseif($data->tstatus==B2bTicket::YUYUE_PROCESSING){
        $msg ="预约处理中，可取消";
    }elseif($data->tstatus==B2bTicket::YUYUE_CONFIRM){
        $msg ="预约确认，电话取消";
    }elseif($data->tstatus==B2bTicket::FINISHED){
        $msg ="体检完成";
    }else{
        $msg ="取消预约";
    }
    return $msg; // show what's going into table cell

},
'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width: 150px'), // also fix this
'type' => 'raw', // or html
```

you should always return or echo something

good day

Comment: tinybyte, why do you think this will work? what is $data here? will php recognize it outside the dataProvider?

Comment: this `$data` represents each item that your **dataProvider** is providing, try it, also read more about unanimous functions in yii and php

Comment: $data->tstatus==B2bTicket::UNACTIVATED this statement will always return false because $data-tstatus will null. Thats due to the fact that only dataProvider knows about $data. You have to write in commas if you want to refer to the $data returned by $dataProvider

Comment: why double **=** ?there is your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
array(
    'name'=>'tstatus',
    'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'150px'),
    'value'=>'
        ($data->tstatus==B2bTicket::UNACTIVATED)?
            $data->tstatus=="未激活":
        ($data->tstatus==B2bTicket::YUYUE_PROCESSING)?
            $data->tstatus=="预约处理中，可取消":
        ($data->tstatus==B2bTicket::YUYUE_CONFIRM)?
            $data->tstatus=="预约确认，电话取消":
        ($data->tstatus==B2bTicket::FINISHED)?
            $data->tstatus=="体检完成"":$data->tstatus=="取消预约")))))
        ',
    'filter'=>CHtml::dropDownList('B2bTicket[tstatus]',$model->tstatus,  
        array(
            ''=>'全部',
            B2bTicket::UNACTIVATED=>'未激活',
            B2bTicket::YUYUE_PROCESSING=>'预约处理中，可取消',
            B2bTicket::YUYUE_CONFIRM=>'预约确认，电话取消',
            B2bTicket::FINISHED=>'体检完成',
            B2bTicket::YUYUE_CANCEL=>'取消预约',
        )
    ),

),
```

Dont use if keyword on gridview   use this contion

```
(condition)?correct statements:fail statements
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem,just name a function of the value as follow:

```
    array(
        'name'=>'tstatus',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'150px'),
        'value'=>"B2bTicket::getStatusDesc($model->tstatus)",
        'filter'=>CHtml::dropDownList('B2bTicket[tstatus]',$model->tstatus,  
            array(
                ''=>'全部',
                B2bTicket::UNACTIVATED=>'未激活',
                B2bTicket::YUYUE_PROCESSING=>'预约处理中，可取消',
                B2bTicket::YUYUE_CONFIRM=>'预约确认，电话取消',
                B2bTicket::FINISHED=>'体检完成',
                B2bTicket::YUYUE_CANCEL=>'取消预约',
            )
        ),
    ),
```

and in the model,name a function

```
    /*
 * 转换订单的状态
 * @param $tstatus 
 * return 状态描述
 */
static function getStatusDesc($tstatus="")
{
    switch($tstatus){
        case $tstatus==B2bTicket::UNACTIVATED:
            $tstatus="未激活";
            break;
        case $tstatus==B2bTicket::YUYUE_PROCESSING:
            $tstatus="预约处理中，可取消";
            break;
        case $tstatus==B2bTicket::YUYUE_CONFIRM:
            $tstatus="预约确认，电话取消";
            break;
        case $tstatus==B2bTicket::FINISHED:
            $tstatus="体检完成";
            break;
        case $tstatus==B2bTicket::YUYUE_CANCEL:
            $tstatus="体检完成";
            break;

    }
    return $tstatus;
}
```